# How to enable and disable Alertaction button based on UITextView text length using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing `UITextView` within `UIAlertController` and two buttons. here, I need to validate Textview `empty` based AlertviewController button `Done` enable and disable using `Swift`.

**AlertView with TextView**

```
@IBAction func alertAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello Alert!", message: "Write Your Text and Informations\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.view.autoresizesSubviews = true

        textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.text = "Placeholder text goes right here..."
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

        let leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0)
        let trailConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -64.0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64.0)
        alert.view.addSubview(textView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadConstraint, trailConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { action in
            print("\(String(describing: self.textView.text))")
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            textView.text = ""
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

        if textView.text == "" {
            textView.text = "Placeholder text ..."
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIAlertController` can already contain `UITextFields`. You can manage the `UIAlertAction's` `isEnabled` state based on whether the `textField` is empty or not.

**1.** Create properties for `UIAlertAction` in your `ViewController`.

```
var doneAction: UIAlertAction?
```

**2.** On `alertAction` button event, add the `textField`, `cancelAction` and `doneAction` in the `alert` created above.

```
@IBAction func alertAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello Alert!", message: "Write Your Text and Informations\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.autoresizesSubviews = true

    //TextField...
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.text = "Placeholder text goes right here..."

    let leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0)
    let trailConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -64.0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64.0)
    alert.view.addSubview(textView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadConstraint, trailConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

    //Done action...
    let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("\(String(describing: alert.textFields?.first?.text))")
    }
    doneAction.isEnabled = false
    alert.addAction(doneAction)
    self.doneAction = doneAction

    //Cancel action...
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

**3.** Now, overriding `UITextViewDelegate's` `textView(_:, shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` method,

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let text = (textView.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    self.doneAction?.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty && text != "Placeholder text goes right here..."
    textView.textColor = (!text.isEmpty && text != "Placeholder text goes right here...") ? .black : .lightGray
    return true
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.text = nil
}
```

Comment: why I need to do `@IBAction func alertAction(_ sender: Any)` separately. I have `lazy var doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { (action) in
    print("\(String(describing: self.alert.textFields?.first?.text))")
}`. by this line I am confused.

Comment: @TestApp I mistakenly pasted the wrong code. Updated that.

Comment: btw I mentioned UITextView. Sorry to mention again.

Comment: @TestApp Yes I read that already. Still adding textField will be much easier that adding all that subview and constrains, if it does not affect your requirement,.

Comment: yes I agree your but as per the requirement I need to add UITextView. what to do? :)

Comment: @TestApp textView can implemented in the similar way. I've updated the code. Check that out.

Comment: Thanks buddy, Btw the placeholder making always submit button enable. That is the issue I am facing now @PGDev

Comment: @TestApp That needs updation of the delegate methods. Updated the code for that as well.

Comment: @TestApp forgot to add this line `textView.text = "Placeholder text goes right here..."`. Updated and done.

Comment: now the placeholder color not changing light gray to black after entered. :)

Comment: @TestApp You can at least try solving these small issues once you get the main solution. Anyways, I've updated that too.

Comment: Sorry buddy. This question will help many new developers. Thats the reason I asked many corrections here. I marked your answer thanks for awesome answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code it's Work

I use `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` for notification name `UITextView.textDidChangeNotification`.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello Alert!", message: "Write Your Text and Informations\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.view.autoresizesSubviews = true

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
//    textView.delegate = self
textView.text = "Placeholder text goes right here..."
textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

let leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0)
let trailConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)

let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -64.0)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64.0)
alert.view.addSubview(textView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadConstraint, trailConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in

}))

let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { action in
  print("\(String(describing: textView.text))")
})

alert.addAction(doneAction)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextView.textDidBeginEditingNotification, object: textView, queue: OperationQueue.main, using:
  {_ in

    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
      textView.text = ""
      textView.textColor = UIColor.black
      doneAction.isEnabled = false
    }



})

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextView.textDidEndEditingNotification, object: textView, queue: OperationQueue.main, using:
  {_ in

    if textView.text == "" {
      textView.text = "Placeholder text ..."
      textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

})

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: textView, queue: OperationQueue.main, using:
  {_ in
    let textCount = textView.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).count ?? 0
    let textIsNotEmpty = textCount > 0

    doneAction.isEnabled = textIsNotEmpty

})

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly I am looking. Here, one issue That is Placeholder. when I click placeholder not removing. Its not working properly. Can you update it one with above.

Comment: sorry to mention again. here, if I click textview the placeholder will be hide but button not hide.

Comment: Again I update code and disable doneAction on textDidBeginEditing now check

Comment: @ Ashish Kanani okey I am checking

Comment: Thanks for your great help btw PGDev answer looks most simple comparing to this.

Comment: Ok then use PGDev answer